# Firewatir: Firewatir is not opening Firefox

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir

FireWatir

I recently started using Firewatir for testing, I followed all the required steps while installing firewatir but I am not able to run the script.

Here is the information from my local machine

ruby version: ruby 1.9.1p429 (2010-07-02 revision 28523) [i386-mingw32]

gems installed:
C:>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (3.0.0, 2.3.8)
builder (2.1.2)
commonwatir (1.6.5)
firewatir (1.6.5)
hoe (2.6.2)
json_pure (1.4.6)
rake (0.8.7)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
s4t-utils (1.0.4)
user-choices (1.1.6.1)
xml-simple (1.0.12)

########I used the sample script from the web

```
#Include the FireWatir file. 
require 'firewatir'

ff=FireWatir::Firefox.new
#Open yahoo mail. 
ff.goto("http://mail.yahoo.com")

#Put your user name. 
ff.text_field(:name,"login").set("User_Name")

#Put your password.
ff.text_field(:name,"passwd").set("Password")

#Click Sign In button.
ff.button(:value,"Sign In").click

#Click Sign Out button.
ff.link(:text, "Sign Out").click

#Close the browser.
ff.close
```

When I run the above script from the command prompt, instead of opening the firefox browser, it is opening a dialog box to select a program to open this.

I really appreciate that if anyone can help me with this or point me to the right directions.

Thanks

Comment: can you run any ruby script from the command line?

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue,not sure exactly how but I followed the following steps:
1. Uninstall and install ruby 
2. gem update 
3. rolled back activesupport from version 3.0.0 to activesupport 2.3.8. 
4. uninstalled JSSH and installed it again and that sure fixed the issue